# How do I live-stream video with OBS to a webpage that can be viewed by iphones and regular computers?

Tags: html, iphone, stream, broadcast

This is a project my dad tasked me with.
He wants to stream live-videos from a birdhouse via the Internet to his and his friends iPhones, as well as their laptops/desktops.

We have a small web domain set up, and my dad previously used Open Broadcaster Software and Twitch-embedding to broadcast.
He has now been banned from Twitch since Twitch does not allow streaming of non-music and non-gaming content - something he was not aware of.

What he wants me to do is to make a replacement for that, basically.
I know some basic HTML5, but I have no idea on how to make something that works in regular browsers as well as iPhones.

Comment: How many simultaneous viewers do you expect?  Do you have your own dedicated server?  There are quite a few possible solutions.  The standard answer is use a proper CDN and they often have transcoding services as well, but there is cost to this.  If you have your own server and only a handful of people watching, you can do it yourself a save money.

Comment: I see. Thanks a bunch.
I did manage to solve it by making a standard Youtube-livestream out of it.
Embedding that in the webpage proved to be good enough.

Comment: @Brad please let me know what solutions/3rd party available for the OBS.